# geting "No lifecycle class found!" in scalatra

Tags: scala, jetty, scalatra

I am trying to run scalatra with sbt using container:start command but i get "assertion failed: No lifecycle class found!" message , this is the full stack trace i got with "last container:start" :

> Blockquote
>   last container:restart
>   java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No lifecycle class found!
>           at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:179)
>           at org.scalatra.servlet.ScalatraListener.probeForCycleClass(ScalatraListener.scala:50)
>           at org.scalatra.servlet.ScalatraListener.configureCycleClass(ScalatraListener.scala:64)
>           at org.scalatra.servlet.ScalatraListener.contextInitialized(ScalatraListener.scala:23)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:446)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:792)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:296)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1359)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1352)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:744)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:125)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:154)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:125)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:358)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:325)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>           at com.earldouglas.xsbtwebplugin.Jetty9Runner.start(Jetty9Runner.scala:122)
>           at com.earldouglas.xsbtwebplugin.Container$$anonfun$containerSettings$11.apply(Container.scala:77)
>           at com.earldouglas.xsbtwebplugin.Container$$anonfun$containerSettings$11.apply(Container.scala:74)
>           at scala.Function8$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function8.scala:35)
>           at scala.Function8$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function8.scala:34)
>           at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
>           at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
>           at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
>           at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
>           at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
>           at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
>           at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
>           at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
>           at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
>           at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
>           at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>   [error] (container:restart) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No lifecycle class found!
>   Blockquote

This is my LifeCycle file is called :"ScalatraBootstrap.scala" and it's content is:

```
import org.Server.Controllers.Controller2
import org.scalatra.example.Server._
import org.scalatra.LifeCycle
import javax.servlet.ServletContext

class ScalatraBootstrap extends LifeCycle {
  implicit val swagger = new FlowSwagger
  override

  def init(context: ServletContext) {
    context.mount(new Controller1, "/*") context.mount(new Controller2, "/string1/*") context.mount(new Controller3, "/string2/*")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ScalatraBootstrap.scala` should be in top package without any `package` name.

remove any package declerations you have in the `ScalatraBootstrap.scala` file.

Answer (score 5):

You may put the bootstrap class in the top, nameless package or set the relevant context parameter like this:

```
context.setInitParameter(ScalatraListener.LifeCycleKey,
  "my.package.MyScalatraBootstrap")
```

Comment: Despite setting **LifeCycleKey** in 
> def main(args: Array[String])

of **JettyMain** as shown below, 

    webAppContext setInitParameter (ScalatraListener.LifeCycleKey, "com.example.app.ScalatraBootstrap")

I get 

    java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No lifecycle class found!

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

In scalatra you need to have a class extending `LifeCycle`. Here's an example from the docs

> Note that there is also a file called Scalatra.scala in your src/main/scala directory. This is the Scalatra bootstrap config file, and it's where you should do most of your app configuration work.
>
> The simplest version of this file, which gets generated when you make a new project using the giter8 template, looks something like this:

```
import org.scalatra.LifeCycle
import javax.servlet.ServletContext
import org.yourdomain.projectname._

class ScalatraBootstrap extends LifeCycle {

  override def init(context: ServletContext) {

    // mount servlets like this:
    context mount (new ArticlesServlet, "/articles/*")
  }
}
```

Comment: My file is called :"ScalatraBootstrap.scala" and it's content is:
import org.Server.Controllers.Controller2
import org.scalatra.example.Server._
import org.scalatra.LifeCycle
import javax.servlet.ServletContext

class ScalatraBootstrap extends LifeCycle {

  implicit val swagger = new FlowSwagger

  override def init(context: ServletContext) {
    context.mount(new Controller1, "/*")
    context.mount(new Controller2,  "/string1/*")
    context.mount(new Controller3,  "/string2/*")
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but as I just got the same issue `No lifecycle class found` and the previous responses didn't solve it, here's what did:

The solution for my case was simple.  I had placed the `ScalatraBootstrap.scala` to `src/main`, no errors were given by IntelliJ. The correct path is `src/main/scala`. This is also shown in the [Scalatra project structure](http://scalatra.org/getting-started/project-structure.html) page, but the formatting might cause one to place it in the wrong spot. `src/main/scala/ScalatraBootstrap.scala` works perfectly.